# Swift FlatUIKit: FUIAlertView not work

Tags: ios, swift, flatui

[FUIAlertView](https://github.com/Grouper/FlatUIKit/blob/master/Classes/ios/FUIAlertView.h) does not work in swift project, although other FlatUIKit functions work normally.

When I code this...

```
alertView = FUIAlertView(title: "a", message: "a", delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "a")
```

I got this runtime error..

```
2015-03-01 18:32:48.852 Oracle[21705:2263344] -[FUIAlertView initWithTitle:message:delegate:cancelButtonTitle:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fc685a41b60
2015-03-01 18:32:48.902 Oracle[21705:2263344] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[FUIAlertView initWithTitle:message:delegate:cancelButtonTitle:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fc685a41b60'
```

I checked FUIAlertView.m. Surprisingly, the arguments are different from I coded as XCode' code completion.

```
- (id)initWithTitle:(NSString *)title
            message:(NSString *)message
           delegate:(id<FUIAlertViewDelegate>)delegate
  cancelButtonTitle:(NSString *)cancelButtonTitle
  otherButtonTitles:(NSString *)otherButtonTitles, ... NS_REQUIRES_NIL_TERMINATION;
```

Then, I tried to add an parameter.

```
alertView = FUIAlertView(title: "a", message: "a", delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "a", otherButtonTitles: "a")
```

But got this build error.

```
Extra argument 'otherButtonTitles' in call
```

Does anyone know how to fix it? Thanks,

Comment: Do a clean build? Does `self` adopt `FUIAlertViewDelegate` protocol? How is `alertView` declared and where?